# On click sound problem volume don't work jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somebody help me for the script, the volume don't work, I don't understand :-(

```js
var should_play = true
should_play.volume = 0.5;
window.onclick = () => {
  if (should_play) {
    should_play = should_play
    let soundSource = "https://kahimyang.com/resources/sound/click.mp3";
    let sound = new Audio(soundSource);
    sound.play();
  }
}
```

Thanks you ;-)

Please help me, I solve my problem

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do here. You are defining var should_play=true //(As a bool) then using this as an object 
should_play.volume = 0.5; Please check the browser console for the error.

Comment: Hi Naveen,In browser console no error, the volume don't change :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
var shouldplay = true;
window.onclick =()=> {
    if (shouldplay){
        let soundSource = "https://kahimyang.com/resources/sound/click.mp3";
        let sound = new Audio(soundSource);
        sound.play();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Sure Tyler : let audio = new Audio(audioSource);
   audio.volume = 0.75; // 75%
            audio.play();